# Animation with position absolute elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

About the animation in jQuery. Consider the following animation of two absolute positioned divs:

```
$('.left').animate({left: '+=' + (window.innerWidth / 2 - $('.left').innerWidth()/2 )})

$('.mid').animate({left: '+=' + (window.innerWidth / 2 - $('.mid').innerWidth()/2 )})
```

Where the middle (yellow) div is centered at the beginning. Why does the yellow div move until the right edge of the window only in Firefox but not in Chrome? Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7vx8L85e/2/)

Comment: In my environment, it actually does (Firefox 38 on current Manjaro Linux).

Comment: Shouldn't it be adding half the screen width to its current position? Am I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: But when it is centered and you add half of the screen width then it should stick to the right edge of the screen, right?

Comment: Yeah. It doesn't stick to the right edge in my browser .. (Chrome v.43 OSX)

Comment: Are you talking about the yellow or the red thing?

Comment: Where does it go in your browser?

Comment: you want  yellow will animate after red ahh???

Comment: About 3/4 of the total width.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code. it should work.

```
$('.left').animate({left: '+=' + (window.innerWidth / 2 - $('.left').innerWidth()/2 )})

$('.mid').animate({left: '+=' +(  window.innerWidth - $('.left').innerWidth()) })
```

The above code should move the `$('.mid')` to the left corner of the document.

updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7vx8L85e/4/

Comment: The question was more about the logic and just an example, what is the logic of animating the whole window.innerWidth when its start position is in the middle? Why does it behave different between browsers?

Answer (score 0):

please test this:
$('.left').animate({left: (window.innerWidth / 2 - 25 )})
$('.mid').animate({left: (window.innerWidth / 2 - 25 )})

Comment: then (margin:auto) remove for box yellow .